# Biber parsing all my dates as n.d

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm trying to add in-line citations APA style using Biber. Unfortunately, Biber refuses to acknowledge the year of the articles and render everything as n.d., IE: (Johnson, 1999) shows up as (Johnson, n.d.). I'm using Mendeley to create the bib file, and the format for the bib file looks fine.

Here's my tex code:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\title{ORT}
\shorttitle{Ortho}
\author{name}
\affiliation{univ name}
\leftheader{surname}
\authornote{None}
\abstract{None}

\begin{document}
Blah blah blah \parencite{Smith1999}
\end{document}
```

The bib entry looks like this:

```
@article{Smith1999,
author = {Smith, Bob},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Users/Bob/smith1999.pdf},
journal = {Journal},
number = {1},
pages = {47--84},
title = {{Article Name}},
volume = {14},
year = {1999}
}
```

File list from the log file:

```
 *File List*
    apa6.cls    2016/07/02 v2.22 APA formatting (6th edition)
    article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
threeparttable.sty    2003/06/13  v 3.0
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
      bm.sty    2016/07/07 v1.2b Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
fancyhdr.sty    2016/09/06 3.8 Extensive control of page headers and footers
endfloat.sty    2011/12/25 v2.5d LaTeX2e package puts figures and tables at end
 (jdm)
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
csquotes.sty    2016/07/14 v5.1h context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
csquotes.def    2016/07/14 v5.1h csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2016/09/07 v3.5 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
  blx-dm.def
     apa.dbx    2016/05/13 v6.9 APA biblatex style data model
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2016/09/07 v3.5 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    2016/09/07 v3.5 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
standard.bbx    2016/09/07 v3.5 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
     apa.bbx    2016/05/13 v6.9 APA biblatex references style
     apa.cbx    2016/05/13 v6.9 APA biblatex citation style
biblatex.cfg    
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
 english.lbx    2016/09/07 v3.5 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
american.lbx    2016/09/07 v3.5 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
american-apa.lbx    2016/05/13 v6.9 APA biblatex localisation
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
config/APAamerican.txt    2012/02/23 v1.25 apa6 configuration for American Engl
ish
untitled-3.bbl
 ***********
```

Comment: The example as given is 'works for me'. Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the resulting `File list` from the `.log` into the question?

Comment: OK, this issue appears with the latest `biblatex` release: needs looking at.

Comment: Do you mean that I should downgrade? (Sorry, I'm not that LaTeX savvy...)

Comment: This has already been addressed by the developers https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/27, version 7.1 that fixes the error should be available soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field year seems to be never part of the labelname declaration of biblatex-apa. It must have worked by accident or some side effect. This here seems to correct the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{setspace}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{year}
  \field{pubstate}
  \field{date}
  \literal{nodate}
}


\begin{document}
Blah blah blah  \parencite{doody} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/27. Maybe move `year` after `date` to be in line with standard `biblatex` practice.

Comment: This is fixed in `bibaltex-apa` 7.1 which has just been uploaded to CTAN. It requires `biblatex` 3.6 which has also been uploaded. As mentioned, you should really put `date` first as the new EDTF date parsing in `biblatex` 3.5+ only works with the real date fields and not legacy `year`.